# Proof that gradient is zero in maxima or minima - Continuity of Gradient

Tags: optimization, continuity, maxima-minima

[image: Nocedal and Wright- Numerical Optimization]

This is the from a proof of the fact that gradient is zero at the minima of a continuous function. This is taken from *Numerical Optimization* by Nocedal and Wright, page 11.

Could anyone explain how the last statement came about from the continuity of the gradient near x*? In particular, if grad f is continuous, how can we talk about the dot product of p with grad of f at x*+tp?

Comment: Why the upvote?  The question shows no research from the asker,  nor does it include any mention of the source of the image/text in the image.  I do know that many  answerers upvote the question in order to try to help legitimize the post they answered.  Big Sigh.  *Shakes head.*

Comment: I have tried adding a few more details

Comment: "I do know that many answerers upvote the question in order to try to help legitimize the post they answered. Big Sigh. Shakes head."  I'm the only answerer here so you must be talking about me.  But I didn't even upvote the question.  So maybe don't throw accusations around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\nabla f$ is continuous at $x^*$ then $p\cdot\nabla f$ is too (since the dot product with a constant vector is continuous from $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$).  The latter is nonzero at $x^*$ so by continuity it is nonzero in a neighborhood of $x^*$, which gives your final inequality.

Comment: If it is non zero at x*, why should it also be non zero at neighborhood of x*?

Comment: That's an immediate consequence of continuity.